# Unique sequence of similar characters in a string using regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I have some test strings:

1. "x"
2. " mm "
3. "x mm"
4. "yy x mm"
5. "xx mm y mm"

I want to make a regex which should match strings 1,2,3,4 but not 5.

**So my constraints for match are:**

1. One alphabet sequence should occur once in the string. (e.g. "y" is a sequence one y and "yy" is a sequence of two y's but they contain same alphabet so they are contradictory and can't occur together)
2. Only specific alphabets are allowed in the string (for my case "xym").
3. Any sequence can occur at start, middle or end of the string. But it should be prefixed or suffixed with non-word character if another alphabet sequence precedes or succeeds it respectively.
4. It is not necessary that all the alphabet sequences must present in the string.

Note:- I want only one regex to solve this problem. Because with separate regex and iteration I have already done it. I am searching for single line solution to validate my string.

**The solution I have tried is:**

```
/(?=^[xym\W]+$)((?=^([^m]*\W)?m+(\W[^m]*)?$)|(?=^([^x]*\W)?x+(\W[^x]*)?$)|(?=^([^y]*\W)?y+(\W[^y]*)?$))/
```

But it is matching 5th case also.

Comment: So the issue with the fifth example is that `mm` appears twice, not that there are four sequences in it?

Comment: Can a sequence mix characters? Is `"xy mx"` valid?

Comment: @T.J. Crowder yes

Comment: @T.J. Crowder No It can't have mix characters sequence.

Comment: What about different lengths? Is `"y mm yyy"` valid?

Comment: @T.J. Crowder length is not a concern if the sequence contains same characters

Comment: I don't know what that means. Is `"y mm yyy"` valid?

Comment: T.J. Crowder  No "y mm yyy" is not valid because y sequence comes twice in the string

Comment: Okay. Please update the question with all of these. Note that "y" is not a *sequence*, it's a letter (character). It matters for clarity, because "y" and "yy" are different *sequences*, but they use the same letter.

Comment: What about partial matches? In case 5 (`xx mm y mm`) the following would match `xx mm y` and `mm` (2 matches) based upon the current constraints and the "can't appear twice" rule.

Comment: @3limin4t0r  No it should not partially match the string.

Comment: Try `/^(?!.*\b([xym])\1*\b.*\b\1+\b)\s*[xym\s]+\s*$/`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/VXOo33/1).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - I knew backreferences would come into it, but I confess that even with regex101's help, I'm not following how you did that. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
/^(?!.*\b([xym])\1*\b.*\b\1+\b)(?:\s*\b([xym])\2*\b)*\s*$/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/VXOo33/3).

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?!.*\b([xym])\1*\b.*\b\1+\b)`  - a negative lookahead that fails the match if immediately after the string start there is

  - `.*` - any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as many as possible
  - `\b([xym])\1*\b` - a whole word that consists of identical chars, `x`, `y` or `m`
  - `.*` - any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as many as possible
  - `\b\1+\b` - a whole word that consists of a char captured in Group 1
- `(?:\s*\b([xym])\2*\b)*` - 0 or more repetitions of

  - `\s*` - 0 or more whitespace chars
  - `\b([xym])\2*\b` - a whole word that consists of 1 or more of the same chars, `x`, `y` or `m`
- `\s*` - 0 or more whitespace chars
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: It failed with this case "mmm yyy xxyyyyx" character sequence must contain same characters.

Comment: @RK_15 `^(?!.*\b([xym])\1*\b.*\b\1+\b)(?:\s*\b([xym])\2*\b)*\s*$`

Comment: It failed with this case "mmmyy yyy xxx"

Comment: @RK_15 There is [no match](https://regex101.com/r/VXOo33/4) for `mmmyy yyy xxx`, isn't it expected? `yy` is repeated

Comment: I hven't tried with the Regex101 website but in chrome console this statement is returning false -> /^(?!.*\b([xym])\1*\b.*\b\1+\b)(?:\s*\b([xym])\2*\b)*\s*$/.test("mmmyy yyy xxx")

Comment: Yes, isn't it correct? It must be false. You say *character sequence must contain same characters* and here, `mmmyy` contains two different chars.

Comment: Oh sorry I get confused with my own question. I was thinking some other case. yes it is correct. Thanks again and sorry for any inconvenience.